# Profit Margin column not available

Tags: shopware, shopware5

In the documentation there is a section for prices where a picture is attached, In that picture there is a column „Profit Margin“

**Doc Link**: [Shopware 5 - Products & Categories - Create products](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/products-and-categories/create-products#step-2-prices)

**Picture from Doc:**
[image]

But i have a shop locally installed inside vagrant, and i don’t have this column.

Is there any setting to enable for this column to show?

**Picture from my local shop:**
[image]

**Shopware version: 5.6.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is part of "Shopware ERP by Pickware" that is part of the Professional license of Shopware 5.

Comment: Thankyou @Rotfuchs, It clears the confusion, as in the documentation it is not mentioned if its default or not. but thankyou once again!  :)